# function that returns two different types

Tags: c#, exception

I should have a function that must return either a `string` of an error (through `try` / `catch`) or a *different type* `T`.

**Example** of such a function:

```
public T get()
{
  T struttura;

  try {
    ...
  }
  catch (Exception xcp) {
    return xcp.Message;
  }
  
  ...
   
  return struttura;
}
```

Comment: Why not just let the exception be thrown and have the caller handle it?

Comment: `out` instead of return ?

Comment: Why return only part of the exception? Why catch the exception if there's no intention of handling it? This doesn't make the code more reliable - quite the opposite. An exception contains much more than a message too - it contains inner exceptions that may contain *more* information than the root exception, a call stack that shows the chain of calls that caused an exception and the location where the exception was thrown

Comment: Agree, just let the Exception be thrown and let the calling method deal with it. There's no point just returning the exception message as you're then missing out on the call stack and and any inner exceptions.

Comment: There are ways to return a result or an error, but they require careful coding, not just ignoring errors. This often results in more complex code than letting exceptions propagate to a level where they can be handled. In Go functions often return a tuple with a result or error. Go code *always* checks whether there's an error before using the result. The equivalent is using `(T,Exception)` as the return type.  In F# and Rust a `Result<TResult,TError>` type is used. In F#, the success and failure are represented by different types, to prevent code from using invalid results

Comment: *Why* do you want such a function? It matters **a lot**. It's impossible to answer without knowing the actual reasons. It's like asking for car tires without knowing what they're for: a small city car in the summer or an F1 car in rainy weather in winter? Perhaps you should just let the exception propagate. Perhaps you need the `IResult<T,E>` type. Perhaps you need the tuple

Comment: You can use [`FluentResults`](https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults) or any other analogs.

Answer (score 0):

There *are* ways to do this, but really consider if that's what you actually want.  It is almost always better just to let the Exception bubble upwards into the calling code.

The first way is to use an `out` parameter.

```
public string get(out T result)
{
 T struttura;
 try{...}
 catch (Exception xcp)
 {
  result = default(T);
  return xcp.Message;
 }
 ...
 result = struttura;
 return String.Empty;
}
```

The second way is to use a `ValueTuple`:

```
public (T, string) get()
{
 T struttura;
 try{...}
 catch (Exception xcp){return (default(T), dexcp.Message);}
 ...
 return (struttura, string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Getting the details right will be a pain - for example, how can you return a default value in the success path? How do you prevent callers from ignoring the error? It's probably better to make the error type nullable to force callers to inspect the values, especially when the result is a number or struct. I've seen systems happily return 0 as the USD/EUR exchange rate due error hiding code

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `TryGet` signature:

```
public bool TryGet(out T struttura) {
  try {
    ...
    struttura = ...
    ...

    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception xcp){
    struttura = default(T);

    return false; 
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
if (TryGet(out var myStruct)) {
  // succeeded, myStruct is returned struttura
}
else {
  // failed
}
```

Or either *do not catch* exceptions at all or *re-throw* exception as custom one:

```
public T Get() {
  try {
    ...
    return struttura;
  }
  catch (Exception xcp) {
    throw new MyException("My message", xcp);
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
try {
  myStruct = Get();
}
catch (MyException e) {
  // Failed, e.Message for message
  Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Finally, you can *mechanically* combine `value` and `message` and return *named tuple*:

```
public (T value, string message) Get() {
  try {
    ...
    return (struttura, null);
  }
  catch (Exception xcp) {
    return (default(T), xcp.message);
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var result = Get();

if (result.message == null) {
  // succceded with result.value
}
else {
  // failed with result.message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The  .net design guidelines https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exception-throwing  recommend  never returning the exception as a return type. It’s always better design to throw the error and catch in the caller.

The guidelines also recommend that if you don’t want to throw the error that you can follow the TryParse pattern https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exceptions-and-performance#try-parse-pattern. Typically you provide both methods, Get and TryGet. The presence of the Try method should indicate to callers that Get will throw exceptions but TryGet won’t. The TryGet also returns a Boolean if the operation was successful, allowing you to handle negative cases without using a try/catch block on the caller.